# Can't deploy Spring-Boot WAR file on External Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

The development team is using Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu server. I downloaded that Tomcat from the server and deployed locally and it works okay.

Now, I developed a spring-boot module, wrapped it into WAR file and wanted to deploy it in the same Tomcat. However, `catalina.bat run` fails to start my spring-boot application. The original application (called `ROOT`) is working fine.

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>kz.iuth.platonus</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.e-iceblue</id>
            <name>e-iceblue</name>
            <url>https://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/e-iceblue/spire.doc.free -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>e-iceblue</groupId>
            <artifactId>spire.doc.free</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20211205</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/nitro?characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

Main application class:

```
package kz.iuth.platonus.demo;

import kz.iuth.platonus.demo.entities.Roles;
import kz.iuth.platonus.demo.services.RolesService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder) {
        return applicationBuilder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
...
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
```

Error on `catalina.bat run`:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\tomcat7\webapps\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
Feb 24, 2022 2:55:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\tomcat7\work\Catalina\localhost\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] for context [/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Feb 24, 2022 2:55:39 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\tomcat7\webapps\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 24, 2022 2:55:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2022-02-24 02:55:44.350  INFO 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] kz.iuth.platonus.demo.DemoApplication    : Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_311 on DESKTOP-961M2T3 with PID 33832 (C:\Program Files\tomcat7\webapps\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes started by BIG SEXY BOSS 3090 in C:\Program Files\tomcat7\webapps)
2022-02-24 02:55:44.356  INFO 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] kz.iuth.platonus.demo.DemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-24 02:55:45.012  INFO 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-24 02:55:45.109  INFO 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 87 ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-24 02:55:45.481  INFO 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1076 ms
2022-02-24 02:55:45.678  WARN 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
2022-02-24 02:55:45.690  INFO 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-24 02:55:45.716 ERROR 33832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5709) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1016) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:992) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020) [catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_311]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_311]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_311]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_311]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_311]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean.<clinit>(ServletListenerRegistrationBean.java:68) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1794) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.99]
        ... 28 common frames omitted

Feb 24, 2022 2:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:992)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5709)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean.<clinit>(ServletListenerRegistrationBean.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:156)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:191)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1794)
        ... 28 more

Feb 24, 2022 2:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\tomcat7\webapps\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1020)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:992)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Feb 24, 2022 2:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\tomcat7\webapps\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [6,000] ms
```

When I `http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, I'm getting `404` error.

There might be some issues in the tomcat configuraions, since I'm using the tomcat directory downloaded from the server, not the default (clean) one from the Internet, but I'm not sure where to look at and what to change.

NOTE: I know that by default after `catalina.bat run` and `localhost:8080` , the default welcome page of Tomcat needs to popup, but in my case, I'm getting the welcome page of `our application` (ROOT). Maybe that's the case, I don't know.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` on something in `javax.servlet` probably means you need a newer version of Tomcat.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I cannot use another versions of tomcat, because that's the one used on production.

Comment: Then your organization needs to fix production. Tomcat is now on version *10*, and version 7 was EOL a year ago.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Alright, what I will do is: download the latest version of tomcat, try to deploy both ROOT and spring-boot apps on it. If everything works fine,I will discuss this issue with the seniors. Thanks.

Comment: In the meantime you need to revise your application to target the servlet version supported by tomcat 7.  This may require a closer study of the documentation.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I don't get it. Do you mean to substitute `        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>` with the version supported by tomcat7?

Comment: If they're making changes, it's best to avoid deploying into an external container at all. Modern applications use the embedded container, which is much easier for everyone.

Comment: Unrelated: update PDFBox to 2.0.25. Use the maven-versions-plugin to stay up to date.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- thanks. Actually, the whole point of this "deploying into the external tomcat" is this: when I deploy a spring boot jar file on the server using `java -jar app.jar` command, the application shuts down after ~12 hours. I investigated as much as I can, but could not understand what's the reason for that... Anyways, that's the topic for another discussion.

Comment: @Dalireeza If the application shuts down after 12 hours you should be able to see in the logs what happened.  Either the Tomcat logs or the Linux "dmesg" logs where the OutOfMemoryKiller reports if it needs to do something.   If you cannot see anything, you may want to enable Java Flight Recorder and/or attach a profiler like VIsualVM to see if for instance memory usage slowly climbs over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Deploy to Tomcat 8 or later

Your error says the interface [`HttpSessionIdListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener.html) cannot be found.

Looking at the Javadoc for that interface tells us it was added in Servlet 3.1 specification.

Now look at the [Which version?](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page on the Tomcat site.  There we see that Tomcat 7 supports Servlet 3.0. For Servlet 3.1, you need Tomcat 8 or later.

Be aware that Tomcat 8.0.x has been superseded by Tomcat 8.5.x.

Comment: Thanks @Basil .Working on it right now. In case anyone interested, Tomcat 10 does not support Spring Boot either, as stated on this thread. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22414